# Iterating two lists, comparing the first column and appending the second column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two separate records. One has only one column with names, and the second one has two columns, one with the same list of names and the other with IDs. The names in the first record are unique, but in the second one they are repeated; the IDs are unique. I want to match one list against the other using the Name column, and append the IDs to the same line whenever the name is the same.

FILE1

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
```

FILE2

```
Name1 ID001
Name1 ID002
Name2 ID003
Name3 ID004
Name4 ID005
Name4 ID006
Name4 ID007
Name5 ID008
```

OUTPUT

```
Name1 ID001 ID002
Name2 ID003
Name3 ID004
Name4 ID005 ID006 ID007
Name5 ID008
```

This is what I have so far:

```
f1 = open('Test1.txt')
for line1 in f1:
    f2 = open('Test2.txt')
    for line2 in f2:
        line3 = f2.split(' ')
        if line1 == line3[0]:
            print(line3[1])
```

But the output is only the last record:

```
ID008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate list to group the cells in FILE2.

Import FILE2 as a dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('FILE2', sep='\t', names=['Name','ID'])
```

Then group by the first column:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Name']).agg(list).applymap(list).reset_index()

        Name    ID
0   Name1   [ID001, ID002]
1   Name2   [ID003]
2   Name3   [ID004]
3   Name4   [ID005, ID006, ID007]
4   Name5   [ID008]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the contents in a `dict` and then iterate through the `dict`and print the contents once it is constructed. The way the contents of the files are read in this case assumes you do not have blank lines between each line in your text files:

```
names = dict()

with open('Test1.txt') as f1:
for line in f1:
   names[line.strip("\n")] = list()

with open('Test2.txt') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        name, id = line.strip("\n").split(' ')
        names[name].append(id)

print names
```

The result would be:

```
{'Name4': ['ID005', 'ID006', 'ID007'], 'Name5': ['ID008'], 'Name2': ['ID003'], 'Name3': ['ID004'], 'Name1': ['ID001', 'ID002']}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this input as Test1.txt:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
```

and this input as Test2.txt:

```
Name1 ID001
Name1 ID002
Name2 ID003
Name3 ID004
Name4 ID005
Name4 ID006
Name4 ID007
Name5 ID008
```

This code:

```
f1 = open('Test1.txt')
for line1 in f1:
    line1 = line1.strip()
    print(line1, end=" ")
    f2 = open('Test2.txt')
    for line2 in f2:
        line2 = line2.strip()
        line3 = line2.split(' ')
        if line1 == line3[0]:
            print(line3[1], end=" ")
    print()
```

produces this output:

```
Name1 ID001 ID002 
Name2 ID003 
Name3 ID004 
Name4 ID005 ID006 ID007 
Name5 ID008
```

Note the use of `strip` to get the equality to work.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is the reason to open the file in a loop. open it before. Second, you print statement does not match expected output. Also, you apply split on the file instead of the line. Here is suggestion how to solve it:

```
# test file1
f1 = ["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"]

# test file2
f2= ["Name1 ID001","Name1 ID002","Name2 ID003",
     "Name3 ID004","Name4 ID005","Name4 ID006",
     "Name4 ID007","Name5 ID008"]
output = {}
for line1 in f1:
    output[line1] = []
    for line2 in f2:
        line3 = line2.split(' ')
        if line1 == line3[0]:
            output[line1].append(line3[1])
"""
expected output: {'Name1': ['ID001', 'ID002'], 'Name2': ['ID003'], 'Name3': ['ID004'], 'Name4': ['ID005', 'ID006', 'ID007'], 'Name5': ['ID008']}
"""
print output
```